# Semantical Error, Symfony DQL

Tags: symfony, dql

I have a query that perform normally with MySQL :

```
SELECT *
FROM td_user u
JOIN td_ranking ranking ON ranking.user_id = u.id
JOIN (
 SELECT x.user_id,
 MAX(x.id) AS default_id
 FROM td_ranking x
 GROUP BY x.user_id
) y 
ON y.user_id = ranking.user_id
AND y.default_id  = ranking.id
```

I try to transform it in DQL for run it in Symfony :

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery('
  SELECT u.*,ranking.* 
  FROM UserBundle:User u 
  JOIN UserBundle:Ranking ranking 
  WITH ranking.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN (
    SELECT x.user_id, MAX(x.id) AS default_id 
    FROM UserBundle:Ranking x 
    GROUP BY x.user_id
  ) y 
  ON y.user_id = ranking.user_id 
  AND y.default_id  = ranking.id' 
);
$results = $query->getResult();
```

I have this error :

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 113 near '(SELECT x.user_id,': Error: Class '(' is not defined.

Do you have any idea please ? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have user_id property for Ranking entity.

Comment: Oh Yes... But how to do that ? I try this but the result is the same : "

SELECT u.*,ranking.* 
FROM UserBundle:User u 
JOIN UserBundle:Ranking ranking 
WITH ranking.user_id = u.id 
JOIN (
 SELECT x.user, MAX(x.id) AS default_id 
 FROM UserBundle:Ranking x 
 GROUP BY x.user) y 
ON y.user = ranking.user 
AND y.default_id  = ranking.id"

Comment: In fact, I have a OneToMany Relation Between User and Ranking. Many Ranking can be link to an user. In my request, I want to fetch the last Ranking of each user... Do you have an idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use native query

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$sql = " 
    SELECT *
FROM td_user u
JOIN td_ranking ranking ON ranking.user_id = u.id
JOIN (
 SELECT x.user_id,
 MAX(x.id) AS default_id
 FROM td_ranking x
 GROUP BY x.user_id
) y 
ON y.user_id = ranking.user_id
AND y.default_id  = ranking.id
";

$result = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have this error : Could not find a named native query by the name "
SELECT *
FROM td_user u
JOIN td_ranking ranking ON ranking.user_id = u.id
JOIN (SELECT x.user_id,
MAX(x.id) AS default_id
FROM td_ranking x
GROUP BY x.user_id) y ON y.user_id = ranking.user_id
AND y.default_id = ranking.id"

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks! It works! Finally, I have no more error but the query return an empty array

Comment: Run query in db to check query result. might be database have no records with respect to query

Comment: just check with selecting id without using * in select statement.

Comment: Always empty =(

Comment: try with simple query and check output is coming if its coming then there is some prb with ur query